# Export the events from third party web apps to linkedin and facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, events

I have a webapp where users are asked to create events depending upon his/her requirements and I need to sync the same details of the event with linkedin and facebook events. I am using java/servlets along with jquery/js at the front event.Is there any libraries available or should I dirt my hands writing codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ and 
LinkedIn API http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1002

Comment: I am aware of this but is der any other java script or jquery  library for this ?